# How to check the value of count in Pyspark?

Tags: python, pyspark

I'm trying to create a query that would allow me to acquire a table where the id would occur at least 3 counts and these id would have a value of 0, 3, 4 in the k column.

```
+---+---+
|  i|  k|
+---+---+
| 1 |  0|
| 1 |  3|
| 1 |  4|
| 2 |  0|
| 2 |  3|
| 2 |  3|
+---+---+
```

My desired output is:

```
+---+---+
|  i|  k|
+---+---+
| 1 |  0|
+---+---+
| 1 |  3|
+---+---+
| 1 |  4|
+---+---+
```

This is currently my code. But it only shows a table where the id occurs 3 times and I'm not really sure how to check whether at least 1 of these counts are 0, 3 or 4

```
    sample= sample.join(
        sample.groupBy('i').count().where(('count == 3')).drop('count'), on=['i']
    )
```

Comment: Your code works fine for me if you change the `"id"` to `"i"`

Comment: Oops, I've edited the dataset. The code works but if there are 3 occurrence where k is not 0,3 or 4, it would still include it. I'm look for a way to find out that in the 3 occurrences, the value of k should be 0,3 and 4.

Comment: In addition to these 3 unique values (0,3,4), what if there is an additional 4th value as well, let's say 7? Would you want to delete all the rows corresponding to that `i`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added one more element `(1,5)` to test.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import count,collect_list, min, col
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
#values = [(1,0),(1,3),(1,4),(2,0),(2,3),(2,3)]
values = [(1,0),(1,3),(1,4),(1,5),(2,0),(2,3),(2,3)]
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(values,['i','k'])
df.show()
+---+---+
|  i|  k|
+---+---+
|  1|  0|
|  1|  3|
|  1|  4|
|  1|  5|
|  2|  0|
|  2|  3|
|  2|  3|
+---+---+

#Creating a list of all elements grouped by 'i'
w = Window().partitionBy('i')
df = df.withColumn('count',count(col('i')).over(w)).where(col('count') >= 3).drop('count')\
       .withColumn('list',collect_list(col('k')).over(w))
df.show()
+---+---+------------+
|  i|  k|        list|
+---+---+------------+
|  1|  0|[0, 3, 4, 5]|
|  1|  3|[0, 3, 4, 5]|
|  1|  4|[0, 3, 4, 5]|
|  1|  5|[0, 3, 4, 5]|
|  2|  0|   [0, 3, 3]|
|  2|  3|   [0, 3, 3]|
|  2|  3|   [0, 3, 3]|
+---+---+------------+

# Creating a UDF to check if 'k' contains ATLEAST one of these three values (0,3,4), irrespective 
# of whether there are other values like 7,8 and so on.
check_for_atleast_0_3_4 = udf(lambda row: set([0,3,4]).issubset(row))
df1 = df.withColumn('bool',check_for_atleast_0_3_4(col('list'))).where(col('bool')==True).drop('bool','list')
df1.show()
+---+---+
|  i|  k|
+---+---+
|  1|  0|
|  1|  3|
|  1|  4|
|  1|  5|
+---+---+

# Creating a UDF to check if 'k' contains ATLEAST and ONLY one of these three values (0,3,4). 
# If 'k' has value 7, then all rows corresponding to that 'i' will be removed.
check_for_atleast_and_only_0_3_4 = udf(lambda row: set(list(set(row))).issubset([0,3,4]) and set([0,3,4]).issubset(row))
df1 = df.withColumn('bool',check_for_atleast_and_only_0_3_4(col('list'))).where(col('bool')==True).drop('bool','list')
df1.show()
+---+---+
|  i|  k|
+---+---+
+---+---+
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer, I am trying to replicate this, I'm having an error "NameError: name 'Window' is not defined"

Comment: I made a correction in the answer. Just add `from pyspark.sql.window import Window`, then everything will work.

Comment: Also add `col` in the first import statement. I have added it now. Code should run for you now.

Comment: If the answer has solved your problem, you can accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a select distinct on `k = 0, 3, 4` before your groupby count.

```
df = df.join(
    df.select("i", "k").where("k in (0, 3, 4)").distinct()
      .groupby("i").count().where("count == 3").drop("count"), on=["i"]
)
```

[image: results]